# Ipod Synchronization with PC (moving files to and from an ipod touch)

Tags: c++, synchronization, ipod

I'm building a PC application in C++, and I need to synchronize some TXT data from my PC to IPod Touch and vice-versa.

How to do it? I have no idea.

Can I synchronize with USB port, or network?

Comment: I would recommend updating your title to something like "How to move files to and from an ipod touch" and add more of a description on what you are wanting to do specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Without paying a (very expensive) license to apple your program will not be able to talk to the ipod. However, If the ipod is jailbroken there are a number of ways you can do it.

If you are only wanting to talk to jailbroken ipods we may still be able to help but if you want stock it is likely out of the price range a single person could afford. Please update your question if you are willing to do only jailbroken ipods.

**Correction**: There are some things you can do. If you have a cutom app from the app store installed on the ipod, I tunes does allow syncing with that app for programs like ebook readers, you may be able to do this to sync. Also you could connect to a server while your app is running and get the latest txt file that way.

But there is no way to just grab a file or put a file on the ipod, and the app running on the phone would be trapped in it's own sandbox and would not be able to see or touch any other files on the ipod.

Comment: Is it so expensive?
Isn't jailbroken ipod outlaw?

Comment: Yes, as i said to work with it unjailbroken (a device that does that: [nike+](http://nikerunning.nike.com/nikeos/p/nikeplus/language_tunnel/) ) then you need to pay a licence, if you want to run it on a jailbroken phone then you can just do a SSH file transfer.

Comment: Jailbreaking is against apple's TOS however it is not illegal. so you could void your warranty but you will not go to jail.